# Consultar Cuál es el mes por cada año con mayor Total de Ventas

Tags: sql

tengo una tabla ventas similar a esta: (con mas columnas obviamente pero no aplican a esta duda)

```
-Año  -  Mes  -  Total
-2011 -   1   -    3
-2011 -   2   -    5
-2011 -   3   -    1
-2011 -   4   -    6
```

---

```
-2012 -   1   -    7
-2012 -   2   -    1
-2012 -   3   -    3
-2012 -   4   -    6
```

---

```
-2013 -   1   -    3 
-2013 -   2   -    4
-2013 -   3   -    7
```

---

```
-2014 -   1   -    2
-2014 -   4   -    3
```

y necesito obtner algo asi:

```
Año - Mes - total
2011 - 4  - 6
2012 - 1  - 7
2013 - 3  - 7
2014 - 4  - 3
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido Mondro a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Añade como etiqueta el motor de base de datos que usas, las soluciones pueden diferir mucho según este dato.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sin la base de datos me queda complicado realizarte la consulta, sin embargo, intenta con esto

```
select año, mes, MAX(ventas) from <nombre tabla> group by año, mes;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, es exactamente lo que intenté y no devuelve valores en la columna con las ventas

Comment: envíame el la tabla para hacer la consulta por acá y darte la respuesta exacta

Comment: Por suerte lo terminé resolviendo con esta misma instrucción, tenía un error de sintaxis y estaba trabajando con Acces, mala combinación.
Gracias por la ayuda :D

Comment: E realidad no me explico como esta es la respuesta aceptada si no da el resultado esperado......

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes lograr con un subquery

```
SELECT T.Año, T.Mes, T.Total
FROM Tabla1 T
JOIN (
    SELECT Año, MAX(Total) as Total
    FROM Tabla1
    GROUP BY Año
) as X
ON T.Año = X.Año
AND T.Total = X.Total
ORDER BY T.Año
```